# Passing int to spring property

Tags: java, spring

I want to pass **int** instead of **string** which is default in spring **PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer**.

```
<property name="mailServerPort" value="${mail.port}" />
```

This give me error because mailServerPort is int type and ${mail.port} is string type.

How can I convert ${mail.port} to int?

Comment: What is the value of mail.port? And what exception do you get?

Comment: `Spring handles conversion based on the target type if possible` I forgot this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring handles conversion based on the target type if possible.

Are you sure you set

```
mail.port
```

value with int?

Comment: Oh! so sorry. I did some mistake on the property name. But thank you for the information.

Answer (score 10):

According to me the casting should work properly if the value of port is proper integer.

Still if you face the problem you can try SpringExpressionLanguage(SpEL) for conversion.

```
<property name="mailServerPort" value="#{ T(java.lang.Integer).parseInt(mail.port) }"/>
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring should handle it automatically, although if it is giving error, you can use the *type* attribute property tag and provide and specify require type.
For Ex.

```
<property name="mailServerPort" type="int" value="${mail.port}" />
```

Hope this helps.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

All above answers will work ok in case property value is provided. If it's empty you may use SpringExpressionLanguage to handle that case and provide a default value:

```
<property name="mailServerPort" value="#{ '${mail.port}'.isEmpty() ? '8080' : '${mail.port}' }"/>
```